# Hook up iPod/iPad to old stereo (No inputs)

Tags: speakers, stereo, ipad

I have an old turntable/stereo unit. There is no radio or tape deck on this. Just the turntable and speakers.

Looking for a way to hook my iPad/iPod into it so it.

I do have an 1/8 inch to RCA adapter but the turntable/stereo has no inputs.

I was thinking I could take the RCA ends, strip them and hook them up to the speakers inside the stereo.

Any help would be much appreciated. I can take photos of the underside of the unit if that helps. All the speakers and electronics are exposed from underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea stripping the RCA ends, but you will need to attach them to the input of the amplifier, rather than directly to the speakers. Try to trace the audio lines coming out of the record player, and attach your iPod cabling to wherever that goes.

You'll probably want to test it out with something other than an iPod/iPad too - just in case you somehow hook into power or something silly.

Insert standard disclaimer about working inside amplifiers here:
There really is potentially deadly voltage in amps, even after you unplug the power cord. If you're not experienced with working inside electronics, this is a very dangerous first project.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's a very old unit with vacuum tubes so your comment about the deadly voltage kind of scares me. Think I'll leave it for now :)

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach is to grab one of those iPod FM transmitter devices and transmit the audio into your stereo that way. It has been done with [modular synthesizers to great effect](http://www.muffwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47520&start=all&postdays=0&postorder=asc), it should be even easier with an iPad or iPod.

Comment: Unfortunately the unit does not have a radio in it. It's just for playing records. Good thought though.

Comment: Clearly, you are going to have to start cutting some dub plates with your music and mixes on it :)